# What is the proper way to host a Rails 3.1 app under a sub-URI using lighttpd and thin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, lighttpd, asset-pipeline, thin

This used to be easy up to Rails 3.0: "thin --prefix=/foobar" was all that was needed. For those who are using Passenger Phusion, there's RackBaseURI - but I'm on Lighttpd+Thin, a combination which is not that popular anymore.

I've tried to start thin with "-R config.ru" and put "map '/foobar' do ..." into config.rb, but that doesn't solve the problems with assets still linking to "/" instead. I also tried setting "config.assets.prefix = '/foobar'" which produces correct links in the HTML, but causes routing errors ("No route matches [GET] /application.css" - no "/foobar" there).

The only combination I've found working so far is config.assets.prefix plus a scope around all routes. That seems messy both because it's not DRY and because (IMHO) deploying to different locations shouldn't require you to edit routes.rb. And unfortunately that solution does not work for production, as the HTML will contain "/foobar/application.css" instead of "/foobar/assets/application.css".

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 4.2:

Do not set `config.assets.prefix`, which is a path relative to the root. Instead:

- In `application.rb`, set

  ```
  config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/foobar'
  ```
- In `config.ru`, set the app to redirect root to the prefix, so development matches production.

  ```
  require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)

  prefix = '/foobar'

  map prefix do
    run Rails.application
  end

  map '/' do
    run ->(env) {
      response = Rack::Response.new
      response.redirect(prefix)
      response.finish
    }
  end
  ```

Running `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` will compile assets into `public/foobar/assets/`.

This should work in both development and production environments.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had the same issue. My stack was nginx + thin (cluster).

In addition to setting the prefix in the applications thin config file, I also needed to add the following line in my `environment.rb` file for the assets to link properly:

```
ENV["RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT"] = "/foobar"
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3946 has more information on this problem, which has been fixed in Rails 3.2.1 to allow the asset compilation using the RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT environment url and generate the correct urls in the assets.